# NIO Reactor Pattern: Receiving asynchronous callbacks inside the selector loop every N miliseconds

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, nio

I was wondering what is the standard/best implementation of that in Java NIO. This is fundamental to implement something like heartbeats every N seconds, etc. Note: For obvious reasons (threads are evil and context switches are slow) everything must always happens inside the selector loop.

**Note1:** Answering Apache MINA does not count, unless you and the framework can demonstrate a clear scenario where this is done in a [**KISS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (Keep It Simple Stupid) way.

**Note2:** Pipes require threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you wouldn't have a background thread for sending heartbeats or timing out connections. Heartbeats are not generally considered performance critical.

You can have the selector wait a specific amount of time and send heartbeats and check time outs at intervals.

Do you mean like

```
selector.select(timeout);

if (System.currentTimeMS() > sendHeartbeatTime) {
    for(Connection conn: connections) 
        conn.checkAndSendHeartbeat();
}

// in Connection
private long lastSend = System.currentTimeMS();
private long lastRead = System.currentTimeMS();

public void writeData() {
   lastSend = System.currentTimeMS();
   // write data.
}

public void checkAndSendHeartbeat() {
   long now = System.currentTimeMS();
   if (now - lastRead > HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT) {
      closeConnection();
   else if (now - lastSend > HEATBEAT_INTERVAL)
      writeHeartBeatData();
}
```

Comment: selector.select(timeout) is much better. I am looking for a simple solution/framework to do that.

Comment: There are much more complications: you only send heartbeat IF and only IF you haven't sent anything for X seconds... you may have multiples timers, not just one, etc. It looks like there is NO framework or standard solution in Java to do that. I wonder why... :)

Comment: It pretty simple to check for, two or three lines of code. I don't see why you need more than two timers (two `long`), one for sending and one for a read time out.  Sometimes you need to write a few lines of code rather than use frameworks for everything.

Comment: I agree, but a framework and/or a nice solution to handle all that wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: You could write a framework to do this and make it open source.

Answer (score 2):

create a pipe, register readable pipe's end in selector, schedule a timer, in the timer callback write one byte into the writable pipe's end. The IO handler should treat pipe readable event as a heartbeat trigger.

Comment: That sucks because you are using a thread (timer) to trigger the timeout. If you have 5 different timeouts for all sorts of things you need 5 different timers. To call select with a timeout is much better so I am looking for a simple and straightforward solution/framework to do that.

Comment: I have just explained a mechanism of waking up a selector by a non-IO operation. What works on the other end of the pipe is inessential.

Comment: By doing a selector.select(timeout) you do NOT need a thread in the other end. Having a thread defeats the purpose of using NIO in the first place.

Comment: The trick with the pipe allows using single selector not only for IO but also for events dispatching. Think wider.

Comment: For that you just wake up the selector and poll from a concurrent queue of events. Again no need for threads!